# Is it possible to use some C source code in iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, c, speech-synthesis

I found a speech synthesizer that supports many languages (http://espeak.sourceforge.net/index.html). But the source code that is available is written in C.

What can i do to make it work on iPhone?

Comment: This project is GPL (http://espeak.sourceforge.net/license.html).  I don't think that would be ok in any iPhone project.

Comment: I would look at Flite instead http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html It's been ported and has a iPhone compatible license.  GPL is incompatible for any iPhone app, free or commercial, because the end-user cannot update the app with their version of the GPL protected code.

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C is a strict super set of C. Which means you can use any C code in your Obj-C project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as it's been ported to the LLVM C-compiler.  You can create a statically linked framework out of it, and then link into your project.

Apple does not allow dynamically-loaded frameworks.

Comment: How can i find out if it's been ported to the LLVM C-compiler? And if it's been, what to do next?

Comment: It doesn't look like it has, but you could probably do it yourself.  Create a new framework project, add the source and compile.  Fix compiler errors.